# Look for string inside dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of words as

`list_example['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']`

And a dataframe consistent of other words, example:

```
     col1, col2,  col3
 0   two   nine   ten
 1   two   three  ten
 2   five  NaN    NaN
 2   five  three  NaN
 2   two   NaN    NaN
 2   five  NaN    NaN
 2   two   NaN    NaN
 2   five  NaN    NaN
 2   five  NaN    NaN
 2   two   NaN    NaN
```

Now I want to loop through the words from the first list and check for every column if it contains that word. If so, then I will give that a value which I append to another dataframe. Here is my code:

```
removed_data = []
lst = []
for word in list_example:
         if df['col3'].str.contains(word).any():            
            alert = 1
        else:
            alert = 0
        if df['col1'].str.contains(word).any():
            sentiment = 'positive'
        elif df['col2'].str.contains(word).any():
            sentiment = 'negative'
        else:
            sentiment = 'unknown'
        lst.append(word)
        lst.append(sentiment)
        lst.append(alert)

df_dict = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['word','sentiment','alert'])
df_dict.head()
```

Now I got the following error: 'error: nothing to repeat at position 0'

At first I thought it was because I got NaN values in my dataframe. But I just can't figure it out. Please help!

------ edit -------

expected output:

```
     word, sentiment,  alert
 0   one   unknown     0
 1   two   positive    0
 2   three negative    0
 3   four  unknown     0
 ...
```

Edited the dataframe so it represents more the real data.

Comment: Can you specify how your expected output should look like ? it will be helpful for us to provide you better solution .

Answer (score 1):

Replace the "append sequence" :

```
removed_data = []
lst = []
for word in list_example:
        if df['col3'].str.contains(word).any():
            alert = 1
        else:
            alert = 0
        if df['col1'].str.contains(word).any():
            sentiment = 'positive'
        elif df['col2'].str.contains(word).any():
            sentiment = 'negative'
        else:
            sentiment = 'unknown'
        # lst.append(word)
        # lst.append(sentiment)
        # lst.append(alert)
        lst.append([word, sentiment, alert])
df_dict = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['word','sentiment','alert'])
df_dict.head()
```

The previous code returns :

```
    word sentiment  alert
0    one   unknown      0
1    two  positive      0
2  three  negative      0
3   four   unknown      0
```

Comment: That is definitely better, but did not solve the initial problem. Good to specify is that (obviously) this is not the real data. But in the real dataset col1 has 549 nonnull values, col2 742 and col3 only 82. Which means that all the other rows it has NaN. Is this something that can cause it?

Comment: Hi, modify your statement to make it more representative of your problem: make it generate it.

Comment: if u use : df.dropna(subset=["col2", "col3"], how='all') ; and only work on filtered dataset. hum, you're specific issue seems to be link to what the data are in ur huge dataset...